# ZMQ PUSHer with no PULLer

Tags: zeromq

I have a ZeroMQ network consisting of a PUSHer and multiple PULLers. The problem is that the number of pullers is unknown and, in certain cases, it can be 0. When the latter happens, socket.send(msg) never seems to return. If I remember well, this doesn't happen with PUB/SUB sockets.

Is there any way to avoid pushing packets when there is no puller on the other side of the pipe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid blocking in several ways:

- Use zmq_poll to check when the PUSH socket is ready for output, and only send when it is ready.
- Use non-blocking sends (ZMQ_DONTWAIT on zmq_msg_send method)
- Set a send timeout to zero on the socket (ZMQ_SNDTIMEO socket option) and handle the error return when the send times out
- Use a different socket pattern, e.g. ROUTER-DEALER with more explicit signalling from clients to server

Comment: If ZMQ_DONTWAIT or ZMQ_SNDTIMEO=0 are used, is there any risk to collapse memory or disk space with messages being pushed and never pulled?

Comment: If you use any of the techniques to avoid blocking, then when 0MQ could not queue the message, it won't block but it will return to your app. You can then drop or queue the message, kill the connection, or take whatever other action works. If 0MQ could queue the message it would not block anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: PUSH/PULL and PUB/SUB have different semantics.

PUSH/PULL distributes the pushed messages between the pullers. You use this when you want to fan out and make sure your stuff gets processed. If nobody is listening, then it will block.

PUB/SUB broadcasts the published messages to all subscribers. If nobody is listening, then messages get lost.

Sounds to me like PUB/SUB is more appropriate to your use case. Fanout with messages getting lost does not make any sense after all.

Comment: I use PUSH/PULL because I thought it better fits my broker-based architecture, where the broker is the PUSHer above mentioned. However, I have no problem in coming back to a PUB/SUB model. Thanks.

Comment: one big different between pub/sub vs push/pull is that pub/sub may lead to message loss, while push/pull will not . In my case I need push/pull